# Texture Paint not showing on 3d view model

Tags: node-editor, texture-painting, bump

I have been following a skillshare tutorial and got stuck on the step with texture painting:
The bump "paint" shows on uv map, but not on 3d view window. I tried texture painting on other models and it was fine, tried flipping normals, connecting a tablet and nothing worked so far. Any ideas ?[image: nder]

[image: texture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the shadow, I suppose the node is doubled accidentally:

[image]

Remove one of them and also check other nodes.

Comment: When I checked with the tutorial, the only difference with the nodes was lack of noise one on mine

Comment: You don't understand me, you have 2 nodes one covering another. Drag it at the side and you will see

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in texture painting but IIRC, you need to have the node with the image texture actively selected in the shader window in order for that texture to show up when painting. In your screenshot, this is not the case so I'm guessing that may be the issue.

Comment: Clicked on the node, switched to texture paint but it still doesn't show